# Need help compile c: 'stdio.h' file not found, 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, gcc

I have vs code on windows 11.  I followed instruction of https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-run-a-c-program-in-visual-studio-code up to "5. Move the mouse over the C PROGRAM folder; it shows a + Click on the button and write the file name as JavaTpoint.c, as shown below.".  Every steps before that was OK.  However, after "Run Code", I got "'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." at OUTPUT window.

I double checked gcc and env path setting. Everything is fine.  I googled all possible sources but can't find anything.  Will really appreciate some help.  Thanks.

Comment: Is this GCC a part of MinGW? Open a command prompt and run `gcc --version` and see if it runs properly. If not, then your environment variable isn't set properly. If yes, try restarting VS Code and retry running. If not, then probably some setting needs to be configured.

Comment: Restart VS Code worked.  Thanks!